# Why is MySQL ignoring the ORDER BY on this condition?

Tags: mysql

I want to show rows that have updated_at more than 3 hours ago. MySQL seems to be completely ignoring the ORDER BY clause. Any idea why?

Edit: as pointed out by Sebastian, **this only occurs in certain timezones**, like GMT+5 or GMT+8.

```
mysql> SET time_zone='+08:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE test1; USE test1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE `boxes` (
    -> `box_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (`box_id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `boxes` (`box_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES
    -> (1, '2020-08-22 05:25:35'),
    -> (2, '2020-08-26 18:49:05'),
    -> (3, '2020-08-23 03:28:30'),
    -> (4, '2020-08-23 03:32:55');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2020-08-26 20:49:59 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT b.box_id, updated_at, (b.updated_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR) AS more_than_3hr
    -> FROM boxes b
    -> ORDER BY more_than_3hr DESC;
+--------+---------------------+---------------+
| box_id | updated_at          | more_than_3hr |
+--------+---------------------+---------------+
|      1 | 2020-08-22 05:25:35 |             1 |
|      2 | 2020-08-26 18:49:05 |             0 | <--- WHY IS THIS HERE???
|      3 | 2020-08-23 03:28:30 |             1 |
|      4 | 2020-08-23 03:32:55 |             1 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Expectation: the rows with "1" should show up first.

Actual results: ORDER BY is ignored, and the resultset is sorted by primary key

I have a hunch it has something to do with MySQL storing timestamps as UTC and displaying them in the current timezone. My current timezone is GMT+8. However, it still doesn't make sense -- I am sorting the results based on the aliased expression, and the expression's value is clearly shown in the resultset.

MySQL version 8.0.21.

I also tried moving the expression to the ORDER BY clause, and the results are the same.

Comment: This is working https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90d72528f3cd67aa86b3e17dd1bea618

Comment: I created the db, table and inserted the data using your create, insert and select. The query works as expected! 0 is the last row, check your data and query again! Best write it in another new query console ;) Usually works

Comment: Using a timezone this isn't working. looks like a bug: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b12eef80b56780d7eb398798db77e57 (you can use timezone < 5 - all fine; timezone >= 5 order by isn't working).

Comment: It doesn't depend on the timezone only. If you change `2020-08-26 18:49:05` to `2020-08-26 16:49:05` and timezone to +3 it breaks as well.

Comment: Use: `ORDER BY (b.updated_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR) DESC`

Comment: @Gosfly it works in UTC, but not in my case which is GMT+8

Comment: @OnurBaştürk it works in UTC, but not in my case which is GMT+8

Comment: @RoyBogado tried that also, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it compares wrong timezones in the background and thus values at the end are correct, but comparisons are invalid (for specific timezones).

> When you query a TIMESTAMP value, MySQL converts the UTC value back to
> your connection’s time zone. Note that this conversion does not take
> place for other temporal data types such as DATETIME.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx/

Changing type from `TIMESTAMP` to `DATETIME` fixes problem.

Other solution may be casting to the decimal number.

```
SELECT b.box_id, updated_at, FORMAT((b.updated_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR),0) AS more_than_3hr
FROM boxes b
ORDER BY more_than_3hr DESC;
```

Comment: Whether the expression is correct or not (I don't really know) it eventually renders an integer and it doesn't sort that number correctly.

Comment: It displays integers, but it doesn't sort by the same displayed integers. It must execute casting between operations.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

> HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY, when referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select expression list do not work as expected because the expression is evaluated on the client and thus can use stale column values from a previous row.

Basically, you can't use a variable name you created with "AS" in your sorting.

The solution is to use the verbose statement you used for the AS in sorting. Yeah, it's verbose. ‍♂️ It is what it is.

Comment: A variable is not the same as an alias.   Order by is expected to work from the alias.  More importantly, the OP said he used the expression in the order by and that still didn't work.

Comment: The bug persists if you replace the alias in the ORDER BY clause with the either whole expression or an integer column position. If even persists if you surround the query with an outer query and sort there.